# Freeform validate radio button

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a form with two yes/no radio buttons. Is it possible to create a validation for Freeform if the 'No' option is selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a group of 2 radio buttons for Yes/No, as long as both radios have a value (lets say "on" and "off") then you can make the radio button required. Make sure the radios have the correct `name` attribute.

If the radio is in fact 1 radio button with on = yes off = no, then you'll have to add a hidden input with the no value in it, so that when the form is submitted there is at least a value for the named post variable.

Comment: I need  a validation for the 'No' option only. How would I do this using Freeform?

Comment: how do yuo wish to validate it? As its a radio button, it only has an on/off option, ergo a single radio button `<input type="radio" value="on" name="myradio" />` either propogates through post as nothing (unselected) or `myradio = 'on'`... Perhaps if you could post a snippet and explain the validation you widh to perform in detail I can post a better answer?